# ¿como eliminar un string/ numero especifico de un dataframe en python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Buen día,

Actualmente estoy haciendo webscraping y tratando de hacer un pipelines, en el trayecto necesito eliminar valores  que se presentan en conjunto como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento eliminar el valor haciendo un recorrido con .pop() el valor que queda es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito es el valor del precio que esta en la columna, también he intentando separar la columna con el split, pero se  sigue quedando el mismo valor, la otra es hacer una Regex para mirar que tal pero no quiero complicar tanto

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega unas líneas de tu `dataset` y el código que has intentado utilizar, también incluye un ejemplo de lo que deseas obtener.

Comment: ¿Lo que deseas es eliminar el 800000?

Comment: Si claro, necesito eliminar el  800000 para estos primeros 10 elementos, pero estoy armando un Dataframe de mas de 450.000, estoy estoy tratando de eliminarlos por posiciones de lista pero me queda ese valor inferior en el dataframe

Comment: Como norma general, cuando agregues código o datos por favor hazlo como texto y no como imagen, de esa forma podemos reutilizar lo que has intentado y tus datos para ahorrar tiempo y poder dar una respuesta que se apegue a lo que deseas obtener. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

La forma más fácil de lograr lo que deseas, es utilizando el `string` con el índice `-1` de cada lista.

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable utilizar las funciones propias de `pandas` en lugar de ciclos ya que han sido optimizadas para trabajar con los `dataframe`.

**Nota 2:** Cree un `dataframe` genérico para mostrar la solución, ya que los datos de tu `dataframe` no han sido incluidos en la pregunta tendrás que adaptar la respuesta con las variables y columnas que necesites.

Con el siguiente `dataframe` genérico en un archivo "sample.csv":

```
    Col1
0   100
1   200
2   300 / 400
3   500
4   600
```

Utilizamos `split()` para crear listas y utilizamos el índice `-1` para obtener el último `string` de la lista.

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].str.split('/').str[-1]
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].str.split('/').str[-1]
```

Al imprimir `df` obtenemos el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    Col1
0   100
1   200
2   400
3   500
4   600
```